# Why pipe not working?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have created one pipe to sort an object array based on the value of the object property.keep  all Objects with property `show==0` and `show==1` are removed,there is no any error and can be seen in the console.

**pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'menufilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class MyMenuFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        if (items) {
            return items.filter(item => item.show == '0',console.log(item));
        }
    }
```

**app.html**

```
<tr  *ngFor="let menu of specificmenus|menufilter" >
     <td >{{menu.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `.show` property is a type of string, and not a number? There is a big difference between `'0'` and `0`

Comment: @CozyAzure Its 32 bit intiger ,im getting the same result in the console while using '0' and 0

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in a plunker? Based on what I'm seeing (and tried your code) it should work just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not returning anything

```
transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
    if (items){
      return items.filter(item =>{
        console.log(items)
        return item.show=='0';
      })
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you look at his syntax properly; he did return the value. Fat arrow notations doenst require the `return` keyword if you dont have the curly braces. Though, there will be no effect of him passing in the console.log as a second argument in the callback

Answer (score 0):

Remove ",console.log(item)" And retry!